# replace the eval in console.log

Tags: javascript, decode, console.log

I have a encoded script i need to decode it by replacing the eval in Chrome console.log

this is the code that i'm trying to decode:

```
var _0x490c=["","length","charCodeAt","fromCharCode","YHNoZXJvaWgmdWpjY3YuZy99YGl0LnBndCZkOy5oY3EmQmdyYy9dWTZ+YzcyZV0+W1suLz0uaGNxJkJncmMvXVk2fmM3MmVdPltbLi86ZC1nPS89e3BndCZZNn4xNGJnO10kMCQqJDckKiQzPyQqJDYkKiQxJCokMiQqJD4zJCokNCQqJGFjclJva2MkKiRwZ2pzYyQqJGBkWWJydWEkKiRhY3JDamNrY2hydUR/SGdrYyQqJCQqJCkpJCokJCpxb2hiaXEoamllZ3JvaWgobml1cmhna2MqJClwNyg2KWJvZ2ppYSlpZ3Nybil","laWhgb3RrJCokYGRZYnJ1YTskKiQgZ3Z2WW9iOyQqJCB0Y2JvdGNlcllzdG87YGRlaWhoY2VyPCQqJHVzZWVjdXUgYm91dmpnfzt2aXZzdiBnZWVjdXVZJCokcmltY2gkKiQ7IHVibTsgYHRpa1l2aXVyOzcgdnRvcGdyYzsgcml1OyBqaWFvaDsgdGNnYjsgcXRvcmM7IGN+cmNoYmNiOyB1aWVvZ2pZZWloYG90azsgZWloYG90azsgdWNjaFl1ZWl2Y3U7IGdzcm5Zcn92YzsgZ3NyblkkKiQ7IGdzcm5ZaGloZWM7IGJjYGdzanJZZ3Nib2NoZWM7IHRjYDtCY2Bnc2pyIHRjcnN0aFlgaXRrZ3I7Z2VlY3V1WSQqJCBiaWtnb2g7IHV1aVli","Y3BvZWM7b2l1IFlZRUlIQE9US1lZOzckKiRWSVVSJCokaXZjaCQqJGlodGNnYn91cmdyY2VuZ2hhYyQqJHRjZ2J/VXJncmMkKiR1cmdyc3UkKiRrZ3JlbiQqJHRjdXZpaHVjUmN+ciQqJGVqaXVjJCokbnRjYCQqJG5ycnY8JCokdWNoYiQqJGBndXIrZ3NyaWpvbWN0dShlaWspamlhb2g5a39yaW1oOyQqJCRbKlk2fjM1ZzQ7XVk2fjE0YmddNlsqWTZ+MTRiZ103WypZNn4xNGJnXTRbKlk2fjE0YmddNVsqWTZ+MTRiZ10yWypZNn4xNGJnXTNbKlk2fjE0YmddMFsqWTZ+MTRiZ10xWypZNn4xNGJnXT5bKlk2fjE0YmddP1sqWTZ+MTRiZ103NlsqWT","Z+MTRiZ103N1sqWTZ+MTRiZ103NFsqWTZ+MTRiZ103NVsqWTZ+MTRiZ103MlsqWTZ+MTRiZ103M1sqWTZ+MTRiZ103MFsqWTZ+MTRiZ103MVsqWTZ+MTRiZ103PlsqWTZ+MTRiZ103P1sqWTZ+MTRiZ100NlsqWTZ+MTRiZ100N1sqWTZ+MTRiZ100NFsqWTZ+MTRiZ100NVsqWTZ+MTRiZ100MlsqWTZ+MTRiZ100M1sqWTZ+MTRiZ100MFsqWTZ+MTRiZ100MVsqWTZ+MTRiZ100PlsqWTZ+MTRiZ100P1sqWTZ+MTRiZ101NlsqWTZ+MTRiZ101N1sqWTZ+MTRiZ101NFsqWTZ+MTRiZ101NVsqWTZ+MTRiZ101MlsqWTZ+MTRiZ101M1sqWTZ+MTRiZ101MFtbKlk2f","mM3MmU7XVk2fjM1ZzRdN1sqWTZ+MzVnNF02WypZNn4zNWc0XTRbKlk2fjM1ZzRdNVsqWTZ+MzVnNF0yWypZNn4zNWc0XTNbKlk2fjM1ZzRdMFsqWTZ+MzVnNF0xWypZNn4zNWc0XT5bKlk2fjM1ZzRdP1sqWTZ+MzVnNF03NlsqWTZ+MzVnNF03N1sqWTZ+MzVnNF03NFsqWTZ+MzVnNF03NVsqWTZ+MzVnNF03MlsqWTZ+MzVnNF03M1sqWTZ+MzVnNF03MFsqWTZ+MzVnNF03MVsqWTZ+MzVnNF03PlsqWTZ+MzVnNF03P1sqWTZ+MzVnNF00NlstWTZ+MzVnNF00N1stWTZ+MzVnNF00NFstWTZ+MzVnNF00N1stWTZ+MzVnNF00NVstWTZ+MzVnNF00N1stWTZ+MzVnNF0","0MlsqWTZ+MzVnNF00M1sqWTZ+MzVnNF00MFsqWTZ+MzVnNF00MVsqWTZ+MzVnNF00PlsqWTZ+MzVnNF00P1sqWTZ+MzVnNF01NlsqWTZ+MzVnNF01N1sqWTZ+MzVnNF01NFsqWTZ+MzVnNF01NVsqWTZ+MzVnNF01MlsqWTZ+MzVnNF01MFsqWTZ+MzVnNF01M1tbKn5vYjtZNn5jNzJlXTZbLVk2fmM3MmVdN1stWTZ+YzcyZV00Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTVbLVk2fmM3MmVdMlstWTZ+YzcyZV0zWy1ZNn4xNGJnXTUxWz1+b2ItO1k2fmM3MmVdMlstWTZ+YzcyZV03Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTBbLVk2fmM3MmVdM1stWTZ+YzcyZV03Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTFbLVk2fmM3MmVdN1s9cGd0JmJj","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","c2N1cipkO1k2fmM3MmVdNzVbLVk2fmM3MmVdNzJbLVk2fmM3MmVdNzNbLVk2fmM3MmVdNzBbKmU7WTZ+YzcyZV03MVstYGRZYnJ1YS1ZNn5jNzJlXTc+Wy1+b2ItWTZ+YzcyZV03P1stWTZ+YzcyZV03NVstWTZ+YzcyZV00Nls9Z11ZNn5jNzJlXTQ0W1suWTZ+YzcyZV00N1sqZConNi8qZ11ZNn5jNzJlXTQ1W1s7YHNoZXJvaWguL31vYC4yOztnXVk2fmM3MmVdNDJbWyAgNDY2OztnXVk2fmM3MmVdNDNbWy99a2dkZ2lrZ3I7Z11ZNn5jNzJlXTQxW1tdWTZ+YzcyZV00MFtbLilyaW1jaDsuKC0vICkvXTdbPXBndCZkO2tnZGdpa2dyPXVqY2N2LmJjamd/WXJva2MvKmppZWd","yb2loXVk2fmM3MmVdND9bWztZNn5jNzJlXTU2Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTc1Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTU3Wy1ke3sqZ11ZNn5jNzJlXTU0W1suZS97eypjXVk2fmM3MmVdNTRbWy5oLz0="];var _0xe28d=[_0x490c[0],_0x490c[1],_0x490c[2],_0x490c[3]];var _0x9c69=[_0xe28d[0],_0xe28d[1],_0xe28d[2],_0xe28d[3]];eval(_xyz____(_0x490c[4]+ _0x490c[5]+ _0x490c[6]+ _0x490c[7]+ _0x490c[8]+ _0x490c[9]+ _0x490c[10]+ _0x490c[11]+ _0x490c[12]));function _xyz____(_0x7c39x4){var _0x7c39x5=_0x9c69[0];var _0x7c39x6=atob(_0x7c39x4);var _0x7c39x7=6;for(i= 0;i< _0x7c39x6[_0x9c69[1]];i++){_0x7c39x5+= String[_0x9c69[3]](_0x7c39x7^ _0x7c39x6[_0x9c69[2]](i))};return _0x7c39x5}
```

is it possible to decode the whole code and how to do it in console.log (chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple replace `eval` with `console.log`:

```js
var _0x490c=["","length","charCodeAt","fromCharCode","YHNoZXJvaWgmdWpjY3YuZy99YGl0LnBndCZkOy5oY3EmQmdyYy9dWTZ+YzcyZV0+W1suLz0uaGNxJkJncmMvXVk2fmM3MmVdPltbLi86ZC1nPS89e3BndCZZNn4xNGJnO10kMCQqJDckKiQzPyQqJDYkKiQxJCokMiQqJD4zJCokNCQqJGFjclJva2MkKiRwZ2pzYyQqJGBkWWJydWEkKiRhY3JDamNrY2hydUR/SGdrYyQqJCQqJCkpJCokJCpxb2hiaXEoamllZ3JvaWgobml1cmhna2MqJClwNyg2KWJvZ2ppYSlpZ3Nybil","laWhgb3RrJCokYGRZYnJ1YTskKiQgZ3Z2WW9iOyQqJCB0Y2JvdGNlcllzdG87YGRlaWhoY2VyPCQqJHVzZWVjdXUgYm91dmpnfzt2aXZzdiBnZWVjdXVZJCokcmltY2gkKiQ7IHVibTsgYHRpa1l2aXVyOzcgdnRvcGdyYzsgcml1OyBqaWFvaDsgdGNnYjsgcXRvcmM7IGN+cmNoYmNiOyB1aWVvZ2pZZWloYG90azsgZWloYG90azsgdWNjaFl1ZWl2Y3U7IGdzcm5Zcn92YzsgZ3NyblkkKiQ7IGdzcm5ZaGloZWM7IGJjYGdzanJZZ3Nib2NoZWM7IHRjYDtCY2Bnc2pyIHRjcnN0aFlgaXRrZ3I7Z2VlY3V1WSQqJCBiaWtnb2g7IHV1aVli","Y3BvZWM7b2l1IFlZRUlIQE9US1lZOzckKiRWSVVSJCokaXZjaCQqJGlodGNnYn91cmdyY2VuZ2hhYyQqJHRjZ2J/VXJncmMkKiR1cmdyc3UkKiRrZ3JlbiQqJHRjdXZpaHVjUmN+ciQqJGVqaXVjJCokbnRjYCQqJG5ycnY8JCokdWNoYiQqJGBndXIrZ3NyaWpvbWN0dShlaWspamlhb2g5a39yaW1oOyQqJCRbKlk2fjM1ZzQ7XVk2fjE0YmddNlsqWTZ+MTRiZ103WypZNn4xNGJnXTRbKlk2fjE0YmddNVsqWTZ+MTRiZ10yWypZNn4xNGJnXTNbKlk2fjE0YmddMFsqWTZ+MTRiZ10xWypZNn4xNGJnXT5bKlk2fjE0YmddP1sqWTZ+MTRiZ103NlsqWT","Z+MTRiZ103N1sqWTZ+MTRiZ103NFsqWTZ+MTRiZ103NVsqWTZ+MTRiZ103MlsqWTZ+MTRiZ103M1sqWTZ+MTRiZ103MFsqWTZ+MTRiZ103MVsqWTZ+MTRiZ103PlsqWTZ+MTRiZ103P1sqWTZ+MTRiZ100NlsqWTZ+MTRiZ100N1sqWTZ+MTRiZ100NFsqWTZ+MTRiZ100NVsqWTZ+MTRiZ100MlsqWTZ+MTRiZ100M1sqWTZ+MTRiZ100MFsqWTZ+MTRiZ100MVsqWTZ+MTRiZ100PlsqWTZ+MTRiZ100P1sqWTZ+MTRiZ101NlsqWTZ+MTRiZ101N1sqWTZ+MTRiZ101NFsqWTZ+MTRiZ101NVsqWTZ+MTRiZ101MlsqWTZ+MTRiZ101M1sqWTZ+MTRiZ101MFtbKlk2f","mM3MmU7XVk2fjM1ZzRdN1sqWTZ+MzVnNF02WypZNn4zNWc0XTRbKlk2fjM1ZzRdNVsqWTZ+MzVnNF0yWypZNn4zNWc0XTNbKlk2fjM1ZzRdMFsqWTZ+MzVnNF0xWypZNn4zNWc0XT5bKlk2fjM1ZzRdP1sqWTZ+MzVnNF03NlsqWTZ+MzVnNF03N1sqWTZ+MzVnNF03NFsqWTZ+MzVnNF03NVsqWTZ+MzVnNF03MlsqWTZ+MzVnNF03M1sqWTZ+MzVnNF03MFsqWTZ+MzVnNF03MVsqWTZ+MzVnNF03PlsqWTZ+MzVnNF03P1sqWTZ+MzVnNF00NlstWTZ+MzVnNF00N1stWTZ+MzVnNF00NFstWTZ+MzVnNF00N1stWTZ+MzVnNF00NVstWTZ+MzVnNF00N1stWTZ+MzVnNF0","0MlsqWTZ+MzVnNF00M1sqWTZ+MzVnNF00MFsqWTZ+MzVnNF00MVsqWTZ+MzVnNF00PlsqWTZ+MzVnNF00P1sqWTZ+MzVnNF01NlsqWTZ+MzVnNF01N1sqWTZ+MzVnNF01NFsqWTZ+MzVnNF01NVsqWTZ+MzVnNF01MlsqWTZ+MzVnNF01MFsqWTZ+MzVnNF01M1tbKn5vYjtZNn5jNzJlXTZbLVk2fmM3MmVdN1stWTZ+YzcyZV00Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTVbLVk2fmM3MmVdMlstWTZ+YzcyZV0zWy1ZNn4xNGJnXTUxWz1+b2ItO1k2fmM3MmVdMlstWTZ+YzcyZV03Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTBbLVk2fmM3MmVdM1stWTZ+YzcyZV03Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTFbLVk2fmM3MmVdN1s9cGd0JmJj","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","c2N1cipkO1k2fmM3MmVdNzVbLVk2fmM3MmVdNzJbLVk2fmM3MmVdNzNbLVk2fmM3MmVdNzBbKmU7WTZ+YzcyZV03MVstYGRZYnJ1YS1ZNn5jNzJlXTc+Wy1+b2ItWTZ+YzcyZV03P1stWTZ+YzcyZV03NVstWTZ+YzcyZV00Nls9Z11ZNn5jNzJlXTQ0W1suWTZ+YzcyZV00N1sqZConNi8qZ11ZNn5jNzJlXTQ1W1s7YHNoZXJvaWguL31vYC4yOztnXVk2fmM3MmVdNDJbWyAgNDY2OztnXVk2fmM3MmVdNDNbWy99a2dkZ2lrZ3I7Z11ZNn5jNzJlXTQxW1tdWTZ+YzcyZV00MFtbLilyaW1jaDsuKC0vICkvXTdbPXBndCZkO2tnZGdpa2dyPXVqY2N2LmJjamd/WXJva2MvKmppZWd","yb2loXVk2fmM3MmVdND9bWztZNn5jNzJlXTU2Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTc1Wy1ZNn5jNzJlXTU3Wy1ke3sqZ11ZNn5jNzJlXTU0W1suZS97eypjXVk2fmM3MmVdNTRbWy5oLz0="];var _0xe28d=[_0x490c[0],_0x490c[1],_0x490c[2],_0x490c[3]];var _0x9c69=[_0xe28d[0],_0xe28d[1],_0xe28d[2],_0xe28d[3]];console.log(_xyz____(_0x490c[4]+ _0x490c[5]+ _0x490c[6]+ _0x490c[7]+ _0x490c[8]+ _0x490c[9]+ _0x490c[10]+ _0x490c[11]+ _0x490c[12]));function _xyz____(_0x7c39x4){var _0x7c39x5=_0x9c69[0];var _0x7c39x6=atob(_0x7c39x4);var _0x7c39x7=6;for(i= 0;i< _0x7c39x6[_0x9c69[1]];i++){_0x7c39x5+= String[_0x9c69[3]](_0x7c39x7^ _0x7c39x6[_0x9c69[2]](i))};return _0x7c39x5}
```

It's still not very readable, because it uses meaningless variable names and stores lots of constants in arrays, e.g. `document[_0xe14c[11]]` instead of `document.getElementsByName`.

Comment: forgive me for my stupidity but how to replace `eval` with `console.log`

Comment: You press the Delete key 4 times, then type `console.log` in its place.

Comment: it worked but still some encoded lines like _0x53a2=[_0x72da[0],_0x72da[1],_0x72da[2]

Comment: I know, I said that in my answer. You need to do lots more work to really decode the obfuscated code. You can find some tutorials on decoding Javascript malware at sans.edu.